# NameNode startup error: No FileSystem for scheme: ht

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I'm in HDP 2.6. When I try to start the NameNode I get the bellow error:

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http 
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2786) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2793) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:99)
```

and when I try hdfs ls command:

```
[hdfs@ambariserver ambari-agent]$ hdfs dfs -ls / 
ls: No FileSystem for scheme: http
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: can u post core-site.xml?

Comment: One point, I did a change to my core-site.xml. I changed the value of Fs.DefaultFs in Ambari. And the problem happened after this change.

Comment: Post the content of core-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

The "`No FileSystem for scheme: http`" error occurs when `fs.defaultFS` property value in `core-site.xml` uses `http` protocol (instead of `hdfs`) i.e. value look like `http://<host>:<port>`.  Correct value is `hdfs://<host>:<port>`